# How to get paired bluetooth devices instead of just connected bluetooth devices in android app

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have got paired device using `BLUETOOTHADAPTER.getbondeddevice();`

I want to get the currently paired device (The one which is connected right now)

Is there any method to get the connected device, not a list of previously paired Bluetooth devices?

Comment: Have your try to check ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice